# A doubt on the proof of the isometric invariance of the Levi Civita connection

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

The Levi Civita connection is isometrically invariant:

Note $F_*X$ denotes the pushforward of vector field $X$

Let $M$ and $M'$ be differentiable manifolds having riemmannian metric $g$ and $g'$. Let $\nabla$ and $\nabla'$ be their respective Levi-Civita connections. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two fields over $M$. We consider the fields $\nabla'_{F_*X}F_*Y$ and $\nabla_XY$. If $F$ is an isometry, we have that $\nabla'_{F_*X}F_*Y =F_*\nabla_XY $. Let's prove that:

**We will use these two facts:**

(1) Let $F:M \to M'$ be a diffeomorphism and $Z$ be a vector field over $M$. The field $F_*Z$ over $M'$ is defined putting $(F_*Z)_{F(p)} = F_{*p}Z_p$. For example, if $(U,x)$ is a chart of $M$ we have that $x_* \partial_i = D_i$, partial derivative with respect to the variable.
More in general, if the transformed chart $(F(U),x\circ F^{-1})$ of $M'$ has coordinate fields $\partial_i'$ we have that $F_*\partial_i=\partial_i'$ and

**$F_*Z=F_*(Z^i\partial_i)=(Z^i\circ F^{-1})\partial_i'$** ..(1')

This allows me to write $F_*Z$ in components

(2) **$\nabla_XY=(XY^k +\Gamma_{i \space j}^kX^iY^j)\partial_k$**

**Now back to the proof:**

Since $g'_{ij} =g_{ij}\circ F^{-1} $ we have that $\Gamma_{i \space j}^{' \space k} =\Gamma_{i \space j}^{k}\circ F^{-1} $ and

$\nabla'_{F_*X}F_*Y = ((F_*X)(Y^k\circ F^{-1}) +\Gamma_{i \space j}^{' \space k}(X^i\circ F^{-1})(Y^k \circ F^{-1}))\partial_k' $, where (1') and (2) have been used

$= ((XY^k +\Gamma_{i \space j}^kX^iY^j)\circ F^{-1} )\partial_k' $ ....(#)

$=F_*\nabla_XY $, using (1') again

**So my question is how did  $\circ F^{-1}$ get factored out to the right in (#) ?**

**it can clearly be done in the second term:**

**$\Gamma_{i \space j}^{' \space k}(X^i\circ F^{-1})(Y^k \circ F^{-1}))\partial_k' = (\Gamma_{i \space j}^{ k}\circ F^{-1})(X^i\circ F^{-1})(Y^k \circ F^{-1}))\partial_k' $**

**but it's not clear how it can be done in the first one: $(F_*X)(Y^k\circ F^{-1})\partial_k'  $**

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood, but does that not follow from the definition of a push-forward, transferring a derivative from $M'$ to $M$?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I am not very confident at calculations with the push-forward, but If I use (1)' again, I get $(F_*X)(Y^k\circ F^{-1}) =((X^i\circ F^{-1})\partial_i')(Y^k\circ F^{-1}) = $ But I have that "$\partial_i'$'" getting in the way that I don't know how to get rid of

Comment: Assuming $\partial_{i}'$ denotes a coordinate derivative on $M'$, this can be written (modulo details) as a push-forward of a coordinate derivative on $M$, something like $\partial_{i} \circ F^{-1}$, and then the entire expression may be interpreted as a derivative on $M$. <> If that works out to your satisfaction, please post your own answer; I'd be happy to upvote.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Maybe those details are the problem, I don't know how to write them .Notice we already had a $\partial_k$ in the expresion so I shouldn't be getting another one. So writing the whole first term and going by your suggestion: $(F_*X)(Y^k\circ F^{-1})\partial_k =((X^i\circ F^{-1})\partial_i')(Y^k\circ F{-1})\partial_k=(X^i\circ F^{-1})(\partial_i \circ F^{-1})(Y^k\circ F{-1})\partial_k$

Comment: The right-hand side appears to be $XY$, which we're aiming for...?

Comment: A note: if the motivation for this question is understanding a proof of the naturality of the Levi-Civita connection, one can avoid computations in coordinates by using the characterization of the LC connection as the unique torsion-free connection compatible with the metric.

Comment: @AlexNolte The motivation was actually understanding the computations in the hand-out, but I wouldn't mind seeing the computation you are talking about, if there is any at all?

Comment: If you have access to Lee's "Riemannian Geometry" (2nd Ed.), such a proof is on page 125 (Prop. 5.13). The point is that the characterizing properties of the LC connection are natural with respect to pullback, so that the LC connection is as well. I like this proof more than a computations in coordinates approach, since it seems a bit less like magic.

Comment: @AlexNolte, thanks I'll chek it out.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang you are right, I think I got it, actually I think there was no need to use (1'), when I could use the definition of the pushforward directly:  $(F_*X)(Y^k\circ F^{-1})\partial_k'=XY^k\circ F^{-1}\circ F \partial_k'\circ F =XY^k\partial_k'\circ F = XY^k\partial_k)$,  if that makes sense I only need to know how to proof that  $\partial_k'\circ F = \partial$

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Actually I made a mistake in this last computation, it works using (1') as we saw before. But going forward with the second approach: the $(F_*X)$ should be acting on the component part only, so:   $(F_*X)(Y^k\circ F^{-1})\partial_k' = XY^k\circ F^{-1} \circ F \partial_k'=XY^k \partial_k'$, how ever that is not the answer we are looking for, I wonder why this second approach is not correct?

Comment: @AlexNolte Actually in the post's computation we are supposed to be using the fact that F is an isometry, but I failed to see at was step is that being used, can you see it?